# How to run test with same data on multiple browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid, testng-dataprovider

I am currently struggling running a test on multiple browser using the same data.
I have my data in xls file and using data provider to supply the data into my test. But when i run the test on multiple browser parallel, both browser open but nothing happens on one browser and the other browser enter duplicate data inside the text boxes.

Comment: post your code also where and what exactly happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by setting:

> Dataprovider to run parallel.

```
@DataProvider(name = "StorageRuleDataProvider", parallel=true)
```